# "Tank needs 8 minutes less" or "8 minutes lesser"

Tags: comparative, comparative-degree

Is this question correct?

> Tank needs 8 minutes less to empty the tank than it needs to fill it.

Should we use 'lesser' here as 'than' is used for comparison. Please clarify it.

Comment: No, 'less' is correct over 'lesser', but your overall phrasing is somewhere between awkward and grammatically incorrect, I'm not entirely sure which.  I would phrase it "The tank needs 8 minutes less to empty than it needs to fill".  (That is, notwithstanding the less/fewer debate.)

Answer (score 1):

"Less" is grammatical here. I suspect what is bothering you is that the sentence is awkward. That does not make it wrong (although some may say that "fewer" is preferable to "less").

> Filling the tank takes 8 fewer minutes than does emptying it.

Comment: "Eight fewer minutes" is a nonsense. Even leaving aside the utter bogusness of the less/fewer rule, what is being compared is the (continuous, uncountable) time, not the number of seconds.

Comment: What is being counted is the **number** of minutes. Obviously, minutes are countable. In fact, I beilieve that the specific sentence asked about sentence references a number used in counting, namely 8.

Comment: MInutes are countable. Time, not being discrete, is not. Would you say "it takes 7.43 fewer minutes"?

Comment: yes, I see now that you were talking about style (you said "some may say"). As a question of style, nobody can object (I tend to use _fewer_ myself, but I find this example jars). It is usually couched as a rule of grammar, and in that sense it's bogus, having been invented by Robert Baker in 1770.

Comment: @Colin, I am going to delete my prior comment. I dislike arguing about style. The original sentence was, in my opinion, so awkward that any answer was likely to raise objections that the answer was too narrow or too broad. "Less" is definitely grammatical. Whether "fewer" or "less" is more euphonius depends on one's taste and how the sentence is rewritten

Comment: @JeffMorrow And how about `Filling the tank takes 8 minutes less than emptying it.`? I'm sorry but to me, `8 fewer minutes` sounds strange too.

Comment: @Anatoli "8 minutes less than" is great. The original question was whether "lesser" should replace "less." The answer to that question is "absolutely not." As I said in my previous question, whether "less" is preferable to "fewer" or vice versa is a matter of taste and depends exactly on the sentence is worded. I personally prefer "fewer" when the comparison involves the "counting numbers." I am guessing that Mr. Fine has a somewhat more complex basis for deciding when "fewer" is preferable. We are discussing style, not grammar.

Comment: @JeffMorrow OK, I got it. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> Should we use 'lesser' here as 'than' is used for comparison.

No, you shouldn't.

*lesser* is not applicable here as one quantity of time (that of emptying the tank) is smaller than another (that of filling it) and it's an exact use case for *...less...than...*.